# How to abbreviate yesterday

Tags: abbreviations

What is the correct way to abbreviate Yesterday?

I'm showing two columns of data for Today and Yesterday but I don't have enough room to show the full word.

```
Today YTD
Today YD
Today Y-Day
Today Y'Day
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use "today" and "yesterday"? It would take less room to put the dates, for example "12/9" and "12/10."

Comment: YTD is almost always "year to date", so definitely don't use that one.

Comment: Don’t abbreviate *yesterday*.

Comment: In the case where I'm showing it is necessary to show Today Yesterday rather than the dates.

Comment: I think you're better off with "Yest." than with any of the acronym-like abbreviations (YTD, YD, Y-Day) that you suggest.

Comment: how about --today;

Comment: Actually I would use "LAST" or "PREV"

Answer (score 3):

According to [this acronym dictionary](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/yesterday), "YDA" is an abbreviation for "yesterday."

Comment: That's interesting to read. But I suspect that this abbreviation is insufficiently well-known to be useful in the context of the OP's situation unless a separate explanation or key is supplied alongside.

Comment: The acronym of yesterday would be **Y**.

Answer (score 1):

If the two columns for 'Today' and 'Yesterday' appear alongside each other, the meaning of *Yester.* (or even *Yestr.* or *Y'day*) would be obvious to the reader from the context.